# PHP session issue: two same time on website = same session

Tags: php, session

Just experienced a weird thing. Using same browser, operating system and loading same website in two different computers results in the same session - so when the computer A is adding to cart, computer B can refresh the page and see the item added in cart.

What is causing this and how can this be prevented? Is this on a higher layer than PHP? Maybe a server configuration?

The website is using PHP sessions.

Comment: How are you using same browser on different computers? Print out session ID to see if it's different or not

Comment: without seeing code, we will never know

Comment: What code is there to show? I am using same browser and version, not the actual same browser. The session ID is not different, that's whats so weird.

Comment: Does this happens every time? Or just with this particular scenario?

Comment: This particular scenario. When entering the website on the exact same moment

Comment: This depends on the system and code. For example when you log in (username/pass etc) perhaps the system checks to see if that user already has a session ID and if so just re-uses that. Also, perhaps the cart is stored based on username and updating persistant cart data (temp dB, Redis, etc) means each browser sees the same thing. But it's impossible to debug without seeing all the code and of course you can't really post enough to check. Investigate how the session is stored and how cart contents are persisted.

Comment: The session and the cart functionality is all based on sessions and never communicates to the database to save anything before the user actually proceeds to checkout. So weird, can there be a PHP configuration for session time before it gets unique?

Comment: @Karem well, its answered down there. Php default session handling can lead to duplicate session ids, you should make your own logic about handling(creating) session ids

Comment: @Eakethet I see, hmm. Just think it is weird that only solution is DB communication/file keeping track of session ids to really solve this

Comment: @Karem Well, php does it the same way, but not some kind of sophisticated approach. And if you choose the DB communicaiton, dont forget to lock table, when you saving session ID, if you dont lock it, it can cause the same problem

Answer (score 1):

PHP session ID is not unique have collisions on high traffic websites.

To overcome this you can keep track of session ID's:

1. Generate a random number using PHP and hash it with md5. Insert that number into the table and that is the new session ID.
2. When generating a number, verify it's unique with a database query. If not, start the process over again.
3. Automatically archive session IDs after 24 hours to keep the table as small as possible.

[Read more](http://www.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=36218)

Comment: So the only option for uniqueness is involving a database storage and automatically archive these sessions?

Comment: @Karem Yes, have list of all sessions and make sure it does not matches